# How to convert a macOS installer .pkg into an .app to run it?

Tags: macos, install, upgrade

I have a complete installer of El Capitan as a `pkg` file and I need to install it. But first I need to make it an app.

I can't do it through the MAS because El Capitan is no longer available.

Is it possible to convert a package into an app?

Answer (score 11):

Whilst [norcal johnny's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254241/40457) is good, it's missing some vital steps. So here goes:

**What you really want to do is:**

1. Drag your .pkg file to somewhere like Desktop if it's still in a mounted drive
2. If your right click doesn't have "Show Package Contents" - Open the terminal and run: `pkgutil --expand InstallMacOSX.pkg installmacosxpkg`
3. Now you have a folder called `installmacosxpkg`. Inside this you should see your installESD.dmg file (if it's not there, give it a few minutes to finish extracting.
4. Once finished, open the `Distribution` file in a text editor or just TextEdit.
5. Look for the line `function isSupportedPlatform(){` and add `return true;` so it reads:
   `function isSupportedPlatform(){ return true;`
6. Now go and delete the original InstallMacOSX.pkg file.
7. In terminal run `pkgutil --flatten installmacosxpkg InstallMacOSX.pkg` (this will take some time to complete, watch for the terminal command returning)

You should now be able to build `install.app` files on modern machines and then use that to create your bootable disks.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! The only difference was that instead of "installESD.dmg" I had "InstallMacOSX.pkg" within "InstallMacOSX.pkg" along with Distribution and Resources.
"InstallESD.dmg" was within the inner "InstallMacOSX.pkg". Tested on El Capitan.

Comment: Doesn't work in macOS 13 which has a different directory tree.

Answer (score 4):

Theres no need to  are this an app. Here’s what to do, since the `.pkg` file is basically a folder (if you will), it includes the “app” that the installer runs.

I think you are wanting to burn/run the installer from a disc/USB? (if not, you can run it from the `.pkg` file itself by double-clicking and mounting the installer.

That being said, this is how to locate and save the `.dmg` file locally.

**What you want to do is:**

1. Right-click on the .pkg file > select "Show Package Contents"
2. Open the Contents/SharedSupport folder and locate the file named
   InstallESD.dmg.

Copy `InstallESD.dmg` to another directory of your choosing. This `InstallESD.dmg` file is what you need to burn/run macOS installer from a DVD? USB.

#### Make the OS X El Capitan Bootable Installer Drive with a Terminal Command:

[image]

1. Launch the Terminal application, found in `/Applications/Utilities/`
   and enter the following command exactly (unless you changed the
   target volume name from ElCapInstaller to something else) onto a
   single line, the text will wrap because it is long, but it’s
   important to have proper syntax:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/ElCapInstaller --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
   ```
2. Hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key and enter the administrator password when requested.

   You’ll then see the following screen text in the Terminal:

   > Erasing Disk: 0%… 10%… 20%… 30%…100%…
   >
   > Copying installer files to disk…
   >
   > Copy complete.
   >
   > Making disk bootable…
   >
   > Copying boot files…
   >
   > Copy complete.
   >
   > Done.

   The target USB disk or flash drive will be erased first and then copy the files to it so that it will become a bootable OS X El Capitan installer. This can take a while to complete, so wait for the “Done” message before continuing.

When you see “Done”, that’s it, your OS X El Capitan installer drive has been created, it’s bootable, and you can use it to update as many Macs as you want to with OS X 10.11.

To boot from the installer drive, hold down the Option key during Mac system start, and select it from the startup volume menu.

---

**Note:** the OP is trying to create a bootable disc via MAS and Terminal method. In the instructions it tells you to download and save the installer, to avoid deletion after install completes and saving it for future use. It goes on to say load the `.app` to continue with creating the bootable disc/USB flash drive. This is why, I assume the user has worded his question as such.

Comment: Re "basically a folder (if you will) that.."; Do you mean `dmg` instead of `pkg`?

Comment: When you open the virtual image that mounts on the desktop(dmg), inside there is the pkg file I am referring to. Cheers

Comment: there is no "show package contents" on the right click menu of the El Capitan .pkg file

Comment: So there's a step missing here:First you need to unpack the pkg with `pkgutil --expand InstallMacOSX.pkg installmacosxpkg` then go into the folder installmacosxpkg and follow the directions above

Comment: @JaredMartin actually I did not use terminal and the step is there under 1) Right-click on the .pkg file > select "Show Package Contents"

Comment: "Show Package Contents" is not always available--it isn't for me, for example. It would be good to include @JaredMartin's suggestion as an option.

Comment: This seems to rely on having the `Install OS X El Capitan.app" already in your Applications folder. That's the very thing I think OP is missing, so this solution won't help.

Comment: There seems to be a missing step after getting the `InstallESD.dmg` file. The next step is to run a file within `/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app`, which doesn't exist yet. How do you go from having `InstallESD.dmg` to having the installer in your Applications folder?

Answer (score 3):

It no longer seems possible to “View Package Contents” using a right click in macOS (version 10.15.7 Catalina in 2020).

However you can use the `pkgutil` command in the Terminal to expand the `.pkg` file as described here:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251038496

The steps are essentially the same as the steps in [Adam Collingburn‘s answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/445329/40457).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to re-download the OS X El Capitan Installer from the Mac App Store, under the Purchased tab.

Answer (score -2):

Just run the pkg and it installs the installer

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on your answer (e.g. how to run the .pkg file, what to expect, etc). Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.