# Help converting .pkg to .app

Tags: terminal, finder, install, pkg

My question is very similar to this post: [How to convert a macOS .pkg into and .app to run it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254223/how-to-convert-a-macos-installer-pkg-into-an-app-to-run-it) It comes very close to giving me a solution, but in my specific instance, I’m trying to install [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/). Instead of following the instructions on that post, I found a very informative video that also *almost* works. I suggest you watch it here first: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn9Mi6t3_Lc.
When I follow the steps in the video for expanding the .pkg, I’m met with multiple .pkg files, each containing a “Payload” file that can be turned into an app (according to the video).

[image: Desktop folder in finder]

How can I combine all of these into a single macOS Application file?

Comment: A .pkg file is data for Apple's Installer app. Your best option is to run it. If you want to install DaVinci Resolve, follow the developer's instructions. If that doesn't work, ask them for help.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here?  Why can't you just install the application?

Comment: What app is it ?

Comment: @Ruskes I’m installing DaVinci Resolve; it says in the question. I just installed it the normal way and I discovered, to my surprise, that it actually does install multiple apps. I don’t need them combined into one because they work on their own. The video probably will work. Thanks for not chastising me about why, I just want to know how because it’s a pain to have to “install” everything when it works just fine to run a normal app. This might also work with Python, VirtualBox, and possibly Java. It’s very interesting to me.

Comment: Apps only use an installer when one is needed [they will also likely need a specific uninstaller too -DaVinci does, included in the install.]. Most apps you just drag & drop into Applications. Trying to bypass the installer 'just for the sake of it' is kind of pointless.