# How can I force an install of an Intel binary on an Apple Silicon machine? In this case, MAMP 6.9

Tags: install, apple-silicon, mamp, intel

Due the fact that [Oracle has not released an ARM version (Apple Silicon) of their Instant Client (OCI8)](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/617) I am forced to use the Intel version of MAMP with my MacBook Air (M2; 2023) so I can properly compile the OCI8 binary (based on the Intel version of the Instant Client) via Pecl.

Okay, that should be no big deal. MAMP basically runs Apache, MySQL and PHP so there should not be a performance hit. [Rosetta translation of Intel code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment) should not significant or negatively impact the use of MAMP at all.

But how I can I install the install the Intel version of the binary (`MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg`) on my MacBook Air (M2; 2023)?

I launch the installer and get this message that effectively blocks and install:

> **x86_64 CPU required!**
>
> You need a x86 CPU (64 bit) to run MAMP or MAMP PRO.

[image]

I guess I could hassle a co-worker to install in on an Intel-based Mac and then just copy the MAMP folder located at `/Applications/MAMP` to a USB flash drive and then install that on my MacBook Air?

But is there any way to force the installer to ignore the CPU architecture mismatch so I can handle this on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes you can!

#### You just have to hack/patch the Intel installer to ignore the architecture mismatch and the install will go ahead as normal.

The basis of this answer lies in the instructions [that exist here in this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/445329/40457) that is focused major macOS installers. The key is using `pkgutil` to expand the package, alter the `Distribution` script and then using `pkgutil` again to “flatten” the directory back into a package.

All steps assume you are working in the same directory as the `MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg` package.

1. Download the Intel binary installer package from [the official MAMP site](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). Direct download link is [here](https://downloads.mamp.info/MAMP-PRO/releases/6.9/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg).
2. Once downloaded, run this command to expand the package into a directory named `MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86`:

   ```bash
   pkgutil --expand MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86
   ```
3. Go into that `MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86` directory and open up the `Distribution` script in whatever text editor that you like.
4. Find the `function installation_check()` which lives around line 222. Remove, or comment out, lines 228 to 233 which read like this; that’s the stuff that triggers the architecture mismatch error message:

   ```bash
   if (tResult==false)
   {
       my.result.title = system.localizedString('REQUIREMENT_FAILED_MESSAGE_INSTALLATION_CHECK_1');
       my.result.message = system.localizedString('REQUIREMENT_FAILED_DESCRIPTION_INSTALLATION_CHECK_1');
       my.result.type = 'Fatal';
   }
   ```
5. Save the file and exit your text editor.
6. Trash the old `MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg` file.
7. Then run `pkgutil` with the `flatten` param to recompress the package installer like this:

   ```bash
   pkgutil --flatten MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86 MAMP_MAMP_PRO_6.9-Intel-x86.pkg
   ```
8. When that process completes you should now have a hacked/patched MAMP 6.9 Intel installer. Launch it and you should see this; just click <kbd>Continue</kbd> to install the Intel version of MAMP 6.9 on your Apple Silicon/ARM-based Mac:
   [image]